# Flags to show a view on top of lock screen

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am trying to add a view(ImageButton for example) to Window using `WindowManager.addView(button)`,

What are the layout params so that the button can be seen on "lock screen".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding type as `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` constructor which is illustrated below :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.type=WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
```

The aforementioned lines will make the view to appear on lock screen where you can capture touch events, click events and many others; However, you can use the below-mentioned flag for the non-touchable view.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`

> Note: As per [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams) The above-mentioned both flags are deprecated in API Level 26 and so you can use the flag TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY as a substitute.

Comment: Thanks for digging out an old question and answering. I appreciate it.

Comment: @tekkavi thanks, anyway this would help for those who has the same problem currently

Comment: Good Reply. Make sure to add the below android permission in Android  Manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an **activity with transparent background** with view on the top which you want to show on the lockscreen. Now call that activity when your phone wakes up.
**Note :** You have to make an service which will start your activity. You have to **register a broadcast receiver to that service.**

Comment: I am aware of how to show it via Activity, thats why i mentioned that i will be using WindowManager.addView()
Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CrackService extends Service 

    {

         CrackView renderView;
         LayoutParams params;
         WindowManager wm;

       @Override

      public void onCreate()

     {


          params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

                        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        wm.addView(renderView, params);

    }

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
    }

    }
```

Comment: you can add a custom View in your Service class

Comment: I dont think that is enough to add view on lock screen. Did you test it?

Comment: recently i created an app based on this code which adds view on your phone screen

Comment: I said lock screen, not just phone screen. Anyway, thank for the effort.

Comment: it also add on lock screen don't worry